# pyTelegramBotAPI - How can I create a message that updates with buttons?

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I recently tried to create a message that updates when a button in the inline keyboard is pressed, but without success.

I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI, I can get the bot to send the message with the keyboard, but I can't get the various buttons to work.

Can you help me? :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a multi-option choice (ie buttons) you use `InlineKeyboardButton` object

```
    options = []

    # buttons
    options.append(InlineKeyboardButton('One', callback_data='1'))
    options.append(InlineKeyboardButton('Two', callback_data='2'))
    options.append(InlineKeyboardButton('Three', callback_data='3'))

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([options])

    update.message.reply_text(response.message, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Make sure to set the corresponding `CallbackQueryHandler` to process the user choice

```
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_handler, pass_chat_data=True, pass_user_data=True))
```

In the example above the method `main_handler(update, context)` will be responsible to process the user input.

Feel free to check the [TelegramBotDemo](https://github.com/gcatanese/TelegramBotDemo) GitHub repository to see a full implementation